# Comparing a number of lists and output a comparison table using c#/Html

Tags: c#, html

I would like to compare a number of lists (max 10) and output a comparison table showing which items are present in the list.

say i have 3 lists

`A{ item1, item2, item3}
B{ item2}
C{ item4, item 1 }`

I want a table showing all the distinct items in A, B, C as rows
the list names as columns 
and inside the grid, I want a true/false showing whether the item is present in the list of that column.

Is there a simple way to do it in html or c#? (im using .net mvc)
Many thanks!

Edit: Sorry for being ambiguous. I am still thinking of the best way to do it. 
What I have now:
a model containing a list of different lists

```
 public class CompareModel
{

    public List<Tree> trees{ get; set; }
    public string someotherinfo1 { get; set; }
    public string someotherinfo2{ get; set; }

}
 public class Tree
{

    public List<item> items{ get; set; }
    public int treeid{ get; set; }
    public string treename{ get; set; }

}
 public class Item
{

    public int itemid{ get; set; }
    public string itemname{ get; set; }

}
```

So now I have a 'Compare' model passed to the View with say, 3 Tree, each contains some items.

What I want to ask is how do I write a View of the model comparing which items exist in which tree while which items not exist in which list in terms of a table using true and false.

Something like this in html:

```
       | A | B | C |
 item1 | T | F | T |
 item2 | T | T | F |
 item3 | T | F | F |
 item4 | F | F | T |
```

the column as mentioned is a union of the items of the trees. How about the true/false inside the grid? Right now I am thinking of a straight forward way to do so:

```
foreach (Tree t in trees){
    foreach (Item i in UnionedItemList){
       result = t.items.Contains(i);
       //Display result
   }
}
```

Is there a better way to do so? Since I would have like 90 items per tree in the real situation. If everything is distinct I would have to run the .Contains() for 270 times. Is there a faster way to do so? Many thanks!

Comment: What is your exact problem? Some data is incorrect in your table? Please show your code and explain what is expected and what you have now

Comment: Yes, there is a simple way to do it in C# (of course you can also have your output in HTML). If you **post your code** (see [help]) and you explain which part doesn't work we may try to help you to fix it.

Comment: What did you try until now? also, where are you taking this data from?

Comment: What format are the lists in? Do you have separate list variables, a list of lists? If you want to get all the distinct items in multiple lists, you can use the `Union` function in LINQ (C#) (It takes 2 collections, or lists, and tells you the distinct set of values in all of the lists)

Comment: Sorry I was not very specific on my question. Please refer to the question again. Thanks for the help! @mirhagk thanks for the help of the `Union` function! That really helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't have to worry about performance with as few trees/items you will have. If you have 10 trees, with 90 items each, that makes 900 calls to contains, which has to run over each item in the tree (90 items) for a total of 81K comparisons in your code. Your machine is measured in GHz of speed, so running this should take such a small fraction of a second that you wouldn't even notice. The big-O notation of this algorithm is O(m*n^2) where m is number of trees, and n is the size of the trees. This isn't too bad for small m and n (which you have relatively).

If this is for a website, and speed does become an issue, there are approaches you can take, but it'd probably be easier/better to look at caching this output rather than making the computation faster.

If you do need to make it faster, there are things you can do. One potential optimization would be instead of iterating over `UnionedItemList` calling `.Contains` on `t`, make `UnionedItemList` a hash table (dictionary) and iterate over `t.items` setting the appropriate value in `UnionedItemList`. In theory this is then just O(m*n), calling only 900 comparisons in your case, but the downside is added complexity, and at this scale the overhead of using a hash table may be worse than just doing it the way you're doing it.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help! Yes indeed I am planning to display the results in a website! I guess I will stick to the original method and work on the output cache!